# Filtering a JList from text field input

Tags: java, swing, filtering, jlist

I have a text field stick to a JList and I need to filter JList entities based on values entered by user in the text field.

For example, if the JList values are `{"one","two","three"...}` and the user types `"three"` in the text field, the JList should select the row with `"three"` value.

```
private void jTbandnoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   
{                                         
     // TODO add your handling code here:
     String tXT=jTbandno.getText();
    jList2.collections.equal(tXt);
    int index = jList2.getSelectedIndex();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, index);
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well you can create method to filter out the values by using

- [`DefaultListModel#removeElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElement%28java.lang.Object%29), and
- [`DefaultListModel#addElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29)

Generally when dealing with data or components that use models, we should interact with the model and not the component. So you can have a method something like

```
private String[] defaultValues =  {
    "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdef", "absdefg", "abcdefgh",
    "abcdefghi", "abcdefghij", "abcdefghijk", "abcdefghijkl", "abcdefghijklm",
};

public void filterModel(DefaultListModel<String> model, String filter) {
    for (String s : defaultValues) {
        if (!s.startsWith(filter)) {
            if (model.contains(s)) {
                model.removeElement(s);
            }
        } else {
            if (!model.contains(s)) {
                model.addElement(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you need to filter, for example in the `DocumentListener` of a text field, just get the text of the text field, and call this method, passing in the model and the filter string. Something like

```
private void filter() {
    String filter = field.getText();
    filterModel((DefaultListModel<String>)jList.getModel(), filter);
}
```

Here's a complete example. You may want to implement some more complicated filtering such as including sorting into search filter. This is just a simple case example.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class DynamicListDemo {

    private String[] defaultValues =  {
        "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdef", "absdefg", "abcdefgh",
        "abcdefghi", "abcdefghij", "abcdefghijk", "abcdefghijkl", "abcdefghijklm",
    };
    private JList jList = createJList();

    public DynamicListDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(jList));
        frame.add(createTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTextField createTextField() {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { filter(); }
            @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { filter(); }
            @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
            private void filter() {
                String filter = field.getText();
                filterModel((DefaultListModel<String>)jList.getModel(), filter);
            }
        });
        return field;
    }

    private JList createJList() {
        JList list = new JList(createDefaultListModel());
        list.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        return list;
    }

    private ListModel<String> createDefaultListModel() {
        DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (String s : defaultValues) {
            model.addElement(s);
        }
        return model;
    }

    public void filterModel(DefaultListModel<String> model, String filter) {
        for (String s : defaultValues) {
            if (!s.startsWith(filter)) {
                if (model.contains(s)) {
                    model.removeElement(s);
                }
            } else {
                if (!model.contains(s)) {
                    model.addElement(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new DynamicListDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** As mKorbel pointed out the obvious, this may be a better use case for a `JTable` with a single column, where sorting and filtering is already part of the API.

See [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: +1 seems like as JTable with one column and without JTableHeader is still better option

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i know it's an old post but is it possible to do this searching from a txt file?Not from a static list

Comment: @AlexKolydas, I don't see why not, you just need to refactor the code to read the file into memory. But keep in mind the comment from mKorbel; use a JTable instead of this list. The tables come with builtin filtering APIs.