# Searching trough jList with key events

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I have a problem with my Java code. I am trying to search trough a `JList`, with key events, but it seems like it can't find anything.

With this event, I am adding values to my `JList`:

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
private void productButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    for (Shop i : shopSettings.Products) {
        model.addElement(i.getProductName()+i.getPrice()+i.getProductCategory()+i.getNumber());
    }
    jList1.setModel(model);
}
```

Here I am trying to search trough the `JList`, with this action, but anytime I write something, it just overwrites the list, and displays nothing.

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    DefaultListModel filteredProducts = new DefaultListModel();
    for (Shop i: shopSettings.Products) {
        String productName=i.getProductName()+i.getPrice()+i.getProductCategory()+i.getNumber().toLowerCase();
        if(productName.contains(jTextField1.getText().toLowerCase()));
        {
            model.addElement(i.getProductName()+i.getPrice()+i.getProductCategory()+i.getNumber());
        }
    }
    model=filteredProduct;
    jList1.setModel(model);
}
```

Sorry, if the answer is way too obvious, I have just getting started with Java.

Comment: If filtering is involved, [I'd use a single column `JTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556) (with a suitable `RowSorter` which can also filter) instead, 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: After formatting your code, I noticed a semicolon at the end of this line: `if(productName.contains(jTextField1.getText().toLowerCase()));` Is that your actual code? Or is it a mistake you made when copying your code to the question?

Comment: Consider adding a `toString()` method to class `Shop`. Then you could replace `i.getProductName()+i.getPrice()+i.getProductCategory()+i.getNumber().toLowerCase()` with `i.toString()`.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758313/filtering-jlist-based-on-jtextfield Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271760/filtering-a-jlist-from-text-field-input Did your try Googling for the terms ___jtextfield search jlist___ ?

Answer (score 0):

could be:

```
 String productName= (i.getProductName()+i.getPrice()+i.getProductCategory()+i.getNumber()).toLowerCase();
```

Best to learn how the debugger works in your IDE of choice and step through the algorithm to see why it doesn't match.

Edit: To be more clear: Call `toLowerCase` on the result of the concatenation, not just the last part.